# Play video while shaking, stop video when again shaking-iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, accelerometer, detection

I am newbie in iOS. I am trying to do a sample with accelerometer detection.
Whenever i shake the device, video should be able to “Play”, whenever i shake again it should be able to “Stop” playing the media. 
I searched in google, but not possible to find any sample of it. Please help with sample code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The following methods will Do it you.

```
    - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder 
    { 
      return YES;
    }


    - (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    { 
      if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) 
      { 

    if(VideoPlaying)
    {
    //Stop video here
    }
    else
    {
    //PLay video here
    }
    } 
    }
```

Also refer the github code [here](https://github.com/ioscreator/ioscreator).

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self becomeFirstResponder];
     VideoPlay=NO;//take it BOOL global.
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

  // for UIEventTypeMotion, available in iPhone OS 3.0
  // UIEventSubtypeMotionShake = 1,
  if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) 
  { 
    if(!VideoPlay)
    {
      VideoPlay=YES; 
      //Play yourvideo 

    }
    else
    {
       VideoPlay=NO;
      //Stop your video 
    }
  }
}
```

For play video custom then check it [this](http://blog.mettletech.co/wp/blog/playing-video-in-ios/) one.

may it will help you.

happy coding..:)

Comment: What delegate method should be used? What frameworks should be added?

Comment: not required any framwork ,and - (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0); deleagte method of motion means shake your device call this method.

Comment: - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    videoPlayerFlag=NO;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                         pathForResource:@"Receive_app" ofType:@"mov"]];
    videoPlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:url];
    NSLog(@"VideoPlay");
      
    videoPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    [self.view addSubview:videoPlayer.view];
    [videoPlayer setFullscreen:YES];
    
}

Comment: - (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    
    
    if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) 
    { 
        if(!videoPlayerFlag)
        {
            videoPlayerFlag=YES; 
            [videoPlayer play];
            
        }
        else
        {
            videoPlayerFlag=NO;
            [videoPlayer stop];
        }
    }
}

Comment: not working means not calling delegate method ...or other issue can you explain more because i haven't ios 5 ....currently i have only ios 6>=0 so...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48350/discussion-between-dhaval-bhadania-and-akshea)